# How can I create a pecan project with oslo RBAC support?

Tags: openstack, python-2.7

I want to create an application with pecan Python web framework and oslo role-based access control (RBAC). How to do that? Scenarios are as follows:

1. I will call the pecan controller using curl or from the browser.
2. It should check the RBAC using oslo.
3. I have a custom policy file with custom rules in my folder.

I want to do the RBAC authentication. Please let me know about starting for this one.